# Run other select if previous satisfies condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next select:

```
SELECT
  calories,
  total
FROM user_food
WHERE login = 'blabla'
  AND date >= '2020-11-14'
  AND date < '2020-11-16'
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date
```

What I need is to run other select statement if in current select satisfies next condition:

```
calories < ((30 / 100) * total)
```

table:

```
calories total login    date
 23      50    'www'    '2020-11-12'
 19      36    'abc'    '2020-11-11'
 10      50    'blabla' '2020-11-14'
 13      50    'blabla' '2020-11-15'
```

In other words I need something like:

```
    if(SELECT
      calories,
      total
    FROM user_food
    WHERE login = 'blabla'
      AND date >= '2020-11-14'
      AND date < '2020-11-16'
      GROUP BY date
      ORDER BY date) is calories < ((30 / 100) * total)
      THEN (SELECT something)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Perhaps a LEFT JOIN is what you need?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is often handled by `EXISTS`.  However, you have not really provided enough information to provide a detailed answer.  But the structure is something like this:

```
SELECT <something>
. . . 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
              FROM user_food
              WHERE login = 'blabla' AND
                    date >= '2020-11-14' AND
                    date < '2020-11-16' AND
                    calories < ((30.90 / 100) * total) AND
                    -- some sort of correlation clause
              );
```